# If the name of the column is in string return 1 in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create columns for every language in the column "LanguageHaveWorkedWith", it would be nice to have a function, however, can be done manually, and then if the language appears in the column "LanguageHaveWorkedWith" return 1 in the appropriate column (name of the language) if not return 0.

[image]

```
# TESTING
df = pd.DataFrame({'Salary' : [23000,50000,32000,30000], 
                   "Country" : ['Sweden','Slovakia','Austria','Turkey'],
                   "EdLevel" : ['Master’s degree','Master’s degree','Master’s degree','Bachelor’s degree'], 
                   "Age1stCode" : [5,30,15,18], 
                   "LanguageHaveWorkedWith" : ['C;Python','Ruby;SQL','SQL','R;Python;SQL'], 
                   })
df
```

[image]

```
# DESIRED
df = pd.DataFrame({'Salary' : [23000,50000,32000,30000], 
                   "Country" : ['Sweden','Slovakia','Austria','Turkey'],
                   "EdLevel" : ['Master’s degree','Master’s degree','Master’s degree','Bachelor’s degree'], 
                   "Age1stCode" : [5,30,15,18], 
                   "LanguageHaveWorkedWith" : ['C;Python','SQL','SQL','R;Python;SQL'],
                   "C" : [1,0,0,0],
                   "Python" : [1,0,0,1],
                   "SQL" : [0,1,1,1],
                   "R" : [0,0,0,1]
                   })
df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `str.get_dummies`?

```
df = pd.concat([df, df['LanguageHaveWorkedWith'].str.get_dummies(sep=';')], axis=1)
```